# numpy specific operation on a vectorized basis

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array about potential sales figure for a shop in a day on an hourly basis.

`test = np.array([1,2,1,5,3,6,10,0,0,3,2,3,0,0,7,3,6,2,0,0,3,5,4,6])`

My problem is that 
- we would never open the shop when the sales is 0.
- we can only open the shop twice a day (each time continuously)

So what we want is that we calculate the cumulative potential sales during potential opening period.

`test = np.array([ 1,  3,  4,  9, 12, 18, 28,  0,  0,  3,  5,  8,  0,  0,  7, 10, 16, 18,  0,  0,  3,  8, 12, 18])`

then we pick the first period where we can gain 28 dollars,
and the last period where we gain 18 dollars. (In case there are periods with the same potential cumulative gain, we pick the latter).

So what I really want would be

`test = np.array([1,2,1,5,3,6,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,5,4,6])`

where the hours to be closed is 0 now.

I can do the cumlative potential sales by this: but I do not know how to proceed with it to reach the last step.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

test = np.array([1,2,1,5,3,6,10,0,0,3,2,3,0,0,7,3,6,2,0,0,3,5,4,6])

sum = 0
cumulative = []
for item in test:
    if item != 0:
        sum += item
        cumulative.append(sum)
    else:
        sum = 0
        cumulative.append(0)

max_rev = sorted(cumulative)[-1:]
index_max = max([i for i, x in enumerate(cumulative) if x == max_rev])
from_max = index_max
while cumulative[from_max] != 0: from_max -= 1

next_max_rev = sorted(cumulative[:from_max] + [0]*(index_max-from_max) cumulative[index_max:])[-1:]

index_next_max = max([i for i, x in enumerate(cumulative) if x == next_max_rev])
from_next_max = index_next_max
while cumulative[from_next_max] != 0: from_next_max -= 1

for i, x in enumerate(test):
    if ( i > from_max and i <= index_max) or ( i > from_next_max and i <= index_next_max): continue
    else: test[i] = 0

print(test)
```

which returns

```
[ 1  3  4  9 12 18 28  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  3  8 12 18]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. What if I want to make it flexible in the sense that I can choose if I can open at most 1 / 2 /3 times as a variable to input?

Comment: And it does seem like it is not safe by using sorted(cumulative)[-2:] - if test = np.array([1,2,1,5,3,7,10,0,0,3,2,3,0,0,7,3,6,2,0,0,3,5,4,6]) instead then the second largest is also within the first opening times.

Comment: Fixed the possible exception, it will look outside the first interval now.